# R package ggcor unable to install

Tags: r, github, installation, r-package

I am trying to install ggcor package but getting this error again and again. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Error: Failed to install 'ggcor' from GitHub:
HTTP error 404.
Not Found

Did you spell the repo owner (`houyunhuang`) and repo name (`ggcor`) correctly?

- If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.

I tried below command for installing ggcor

install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("houyunhuang/ggcor")

ggcor should install using above command but don't know why getting error.

Thank you

Rishikesh

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `devtools::install_github("houyunhuang/ggcorrr")`?

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer of that package has closed his Github account, so it is no longer available.

This is one reason to avoid packages distributed only on Github -- they might disappear without warning.  If it had been distributed by CRAN, it would probably still be available -- they intend to keep the vast majority of packages forever.  (There are exceptions for packages that should never have been released because they violate someone's copyright, and sometimes if a package no longer works it's harder to get to it, but most packages that were ever accepted by CRAN are still there.)

There are also some reasons why you might want to use a package that is only on Github, or a version of a package newer than what is on CRAN:  usually new features and bug fixes appear there first, for example.  If you do, you should watch out for disappearances, unannounced changes, incompatibilities with other packages, etc.  If the package is important and you believe you can handle those issues, then go ahead.

Comment: Then I can't get this package. Its required for microeco package

Comment: @Rishikesh:  If you need `ggcor` only to support installing `microeco`, then you (or the maintainer) could probably modify `microeco` to remove that dependency.

Comment: ... but I just installed `microeco` from CRAN.  So maybe you don't need `ggcor` at all.

Comment: I disagree 90% with *"avoid packages distributed on Github"*, the hardest language I suggest is "be somewhat cautious of them".

Comment: @r2evans:  I think you left out some important context.  What I said was that the lack of permanence is "one reason to avoid packages distributed on Github".  I can't see how you could disagree with that statement, even if you believe that there are also reasons why you would use packages that are only on Github.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I'll think of it in my head as *"one of several valid reason to avoid packages on github is their possible lack of permanence"*, though there are clearly times when this is unavoidable or it is actually advantageous to wander outside the realm of CRAN. May I suggest that edit? My point being that there are times when it is necessary or good to use github as the primary/only source for select packages (clearly not all or most). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @r2evans:  I've added some text to balance the negativity.

Comment: @user2554330 I need it because there is a analysis i want to do correlation map with mantel test, which requires microeco package along with ggcor package.